# CucumberBackendException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

When trying to run step defs with abstract class contains all the context configuration spring sees 2 differnt beans parent and stepdef

I'm using spring boot version: 2.6.4 , with Junit 5 and cucumber version 7.2.3

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CoreApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AbstractIntegrationTest.Config.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest implements En {}

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example/bdd")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example.bdd")
public class CucumberIntegrationTest {
}

public class MyStepdefs extends AbstractIntegrationTest{

    public MyStepdefs() {
        When("^client post to \"([^\"]*)\" with valid data$", (String arg0) -> {
        });
        Then("^the client receives status code of (\\d+)$", (Integer arg0) -> {
        });
    }
}
```

Exception Stack trace:

io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.orange.ces.core.bdd.AbstractIntegrationTest' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: com.orange.ces.core.bdd.MyStepdefs,com.orange.ces.core.bdd.AbstractIntegrationTest
at io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.notifyTestContextManagerAboutAfterTestMethod(TestContextAdaptor.java:124)
at io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.stop(TestContextAdaptor.java:107)
at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.stop(SpringFactory.java:161)
at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.disposeBackendWorlds(Runner.java:156)
at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:78)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$6(Runtime.java:128)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$3(CucumberExecutionContext.java:151)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:151)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$7(Runtime.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:249)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$runFeatures$3(Runtime.java:110)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:199)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.runFeatures(Runtime.java:111)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$0(Runtime.java:82)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.execute(Runtime.java:94)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:80)
at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.orange.ces.core.bdd.AbstractIntegrationTest' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: com.orange.ces.core.bdd.MyStepdefs,com.orange.ces.core.bdd.AbstractIntegrationTest
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
at io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.notifyTestContextManagerAboutAfterTestMethod(TestContextAdaptor.java:120)
... 30 more

Comment: I see the same exception. The issue is caused by the @CucumberContextConfiguration annotation you have in the base class. 

As a workaround, I annotated my stepDef class directly. I know it is not ideal. But solves the issue. :(

Comment: Yes, I had to do this also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have several step definition classes, you can create a stub class with annotations only

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AbstractIntegrationTest.Config.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class StubConfig { }
```

Place it into a separate package and mention it in @CucumberOptions (if you have it)
Another ugly workaround:(